# Index a DateField (or any non-TextField field) with regex in Solr

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I want to stored a serialized data in documents with a custom field like:

```
<fieldType name="custom_dates" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
                      pattern="^.*?\|(.*)$" replacement="$1"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

should index a input like `birthday|2000-01-01T00:00:00Z` with only regexp replacement part `2000-01-01T00:00:00Z`, while stored full input value `birthday|2000-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

but the tokenizer is not supported under class `DateField` but only `TextField`. if I change class to `TextField` it can't do date operation in search query.

is there any possible to replacing index value with regexp in a non-textfield?

Comment: A `docValue` has a very specific meaning in Solr - do you really want a separate value stored in the underlying docValues column, or do you mean that you want the _stored_ value that Solr returns to be `birthday|<date>`, while the indexed value (and thus the docValue) is based on just the date part? (those values are normally invisible to clients, as they're only part of the index)

Comment: Thanks for clearfying that. as you said I want my Solr returns whole input string to client while indexed with it's date part.